# Prevent Duplicate items in Launchpad from mounted partition

Tags: macos, launchpad

I have a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard. I partitioned the HD, installed Lion on the new partition and used Migration Assistant to copy settings and Applications.

I now have duplicates for most Applications, many seem to point to the Snow Leopard Applications.

I can't find a way to easily identify which apps are Snow Leopard so I can delete them.

The alternative would be to trash the Launchpad db, but how do I prevent Lion from recreating the Snow Leopard items?

Comment: What happens if you unmount the SL partition (or exclude it from spotlight) and trash and rebuild the LP database? Do the apps repopulate when you mount or allow spotlight to see them again?

Answer (score 1):

What if you ejected the Snow Leopard partition and then looked to see which apps disappeared from Launchpad? Would that be helpful?

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but it did not seem to help.

I did some more digging and it seems the problem may be Migration Assistant

I tried the 2 copies of Photo Booth, and found one would not run. The error message indicated it was in /Applications/Apple